# fuelUx scheduler loose the information of day when we select weekly recurrence

Tags: javascript, json, scheduler, fuelux

In fuelUX scheduler, after i call the method `$('#myscheduler').scheduler("value","JSON VALUE")` and if we select weekly recurrence pattern the the information of day is lost for example my input for recurrence pattern is  : `FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE;INTERVAL=2;`  I will get `FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=;INTERVAL=2;`. Is something wrong I am doing here? I have attached a [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/wt4x0f5d/12/)

Comment: Issue [Reported](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/992)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm late to the party but have you seen your issue has been assigned to the 3.7 milestone of the FuelUX pipeline?

I have the same problem and modified the fuelux scheduler.js until the fix arrives as per the following:

At around line #282 you'll see:

```
else if(repeat === 'weekly') {
    days = [];
    this.$element.find('.repeat-days-of-the-week .btn-group input:checked').each(function ()
    {
        days.push($(this).data().value);
    });
```

I changed this to the following. It works for me thus far:

```
else if(repeat === 'weekly') {
    days = [];
    this.$element.find('.repeat-days-of-the-week .btn-group input').each(function ()
    {
        if ($(this.parentElement).hasClass("active"))
        {
            days.push($(this).data().value);
        }
    });
```

NOTE: The selector 'input:checked' has been changed to just select all 'input' and then we check for the parent element 'active' status. This works for an unchanged from initial loading and a modified schedule.

I hope that helps you or anybody else finding this.

Cheers